# Optimize PyQt5 QAbstractView for Pandas Model

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5, qabstracttablemodel

I am currently writing a SQL query interface through Python. 
When writing the data into a QTableView, I am using a QAbstractTableModel to write the query result.

This works fine for smaller queries, but becomes extremely slow when trying to present many rows and columns. Is there anyway to increase the speed that the dataframe is loaded into the QTableView?

Here is the code for my QAbtractTableModel class:

```
class SQLConnection_PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, reason, df, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._df = df.copy()
        self.original_df = df

        self.reason = reason

        # PyQt5 Slots and Signals
        if self.reason == 'Read':
            self.conSig = sqlWindow()
            self.conSig.dataChanged.connect(self.conSig.sql_table_updated)
        # set the shortcut ctrl+F for find in menu
        self.find_list_row = []
        # setup menu options

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError,):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError,):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            #print(type(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))
            if isinstance(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()], bytes):

                return QtCore.QVariant('(BLOB)')
            else:

                return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))


    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]

        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode

            dtype = self._df[col].dtype

            if dtype != object:
                if ((np.issubdtype(dtype, np.integer)) or isinstance(dtype, int)) and value.isnumeric():
                    value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
                    self._df.loc[row, col] = value

                    # This is the signal to my RDB class that a cell has changed and to update the rdb_DF.
                    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole and self.reason == 'Read':
                        #print('Emitting 1',row , col)
                        self.conSig.dataChanged.emit(row, col, value)
                    return True
                elif ((np.issubdtype(dtype, np.integer)) or isinstance(dtype, int)) and not(value.isnumeric()):
                    return False
                else:

                    value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
                    self._df.loc[row, col] = value

                    # This is the signal to my RDB class that a cell has changed and to update the rdb_DF.
                    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole and self.reason == 'Read':
                        #print('Emitting 2', row, col)
                        self.conSig.dataChanged.emit(row, col, value)
                    return True
            else:
                self._df.loc[row, col] = value

                # This is the signal to my RDB class that a cell has changed and to update the rdb_DF.
                if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole and self.reason == 'Read':
                    #print('Emitting 3', row, col)
                    self.original_df.at[row, col] = value
                    #print(self.original_df)
                    self.conSig.dataChanged.emit(row, col, self.original_df)
                return True



    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending=order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
```

I would appreciate any assistance I could get in increasing the speed that the dataframe is loaded.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answered my own question. For those in the future that are running into an issue where you are trying to populate QTableViews using a QAbstractTableModel with large datasets...here you go:

```
class SQLConnection_PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, reason, df, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._df = np.array(df.values)
        self.original_df = df.copy()

        self._cols = df.columns
        self.r, self.c = np.shape(self._df)

        self.reason = reason

        # PyQt5 Slots and Signals
        if self.reason == 'Read':
            self.conSig = sqlWindow()
            self.conSig.dataChanged.connect(self.conSig.sql_table_updated)
        # set the shortcut ctrl+F for find in menu
        self.find_list_row = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.r

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.c

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                if isinstance(self._df[index.row(), index.column()], bytes):
                    row = self._df[index.row()][0] - 1
                    col = self._df[index.column()][0] -1
                    self._df[row, col] = '(BLOB)'
                    return str('(BLOB)')

                return str(self._df[index.row(),index.column()])
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df[index.row()]
        col = self._df[index.column()]

        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df.dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        table_row = row[0]-1
        table_col = col[0]-1
        self._df[table_row, table_col] = value
        # This is the signal to my RDB class that a cell has changed and to update the rdb_DF.
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole and self.reason == 'Read':
            column_name = self.original_df.columns[table_col]
            self.original_df.loc[table_row ,column_name] = value

            my_df = pd.DataFrame(self._df)
            my_df.columns = self.original_df.columns
            self.conSig.dataChanged.emit(table_row, table_col, my_df)
        return True

    def headerData(self, p_int, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._cols[p_int]
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return p_int
        return None

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending=order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
```

I converted the pandas df into a numpy array and that really sped it up. Finally, I convert the numpy back to pandas when I need to print out. This increased the speed drastically.

Pandas loading time for 120k rows and 10 columns: ~280 seconds.
Numpy loading time for 120k rows and 10 columns: 6.634 seconds.

Comment: Note that you should always return the base implementation from `data()` and `headerData()` if you're not managing it.